# WordPress AJAX response returns "false" whenever WordPress Functions are used

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm simply trying to replace the content of an element on my page with content that I've put in a separate PHP file. Everything seems to work okay, so long as the content I'm calling for doesn't contain any WordPress functions; i.e.:

`<div><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>`

When I do use WordPress functions, I receive a response of 'false'. Just `false`; and not `<div>false</div>`. Not that that's the result I'm looking for either. There's got to be a fundamental piece of this that I'm overlooking.

Here's the relevant parts that I'm working with:

**functions.php**

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';


//Load jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

//Define AJAX URL
function myplugin_ajaxurl() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
    </script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');

//The Javascript
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // This does the ajax request (The Call).
        $( "#button_leadership" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
                data: {
                    'action':'example_ajax_request' // This is our PHP function below
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
                    document.getElementById("ajax-container-team-tiles").textContent = "";
                    document.getElementById("ajax-container-team-tiles").innerHTML = response.responseJSON;
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    window.alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    <?php }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
    
    //The PHP
    function example_ajax_request() {
        $filesystem = new WP_Filesystem_Direct( true );
        $someThing = $filesystem->get_contents( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ajax-calls/addition.php');
        wp_send_json($someThing);
    }
    
    // This bit is a special action hook that works with the WordPress AJAX functionality.
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

**addition.php:**

```
<div><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the rest_api_init hook to add your endpoint: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `get_the_title()` is intended to be used in a theme template, rather than an AJAX request. You'll probably need to pass the ID of the post as a parameter in the request, and then pass it to the function:

#### functions.php

```
data: {
    'action':'example_ajax_request',
    'post_id': <?php echo (int) get_the_ID() ?>,
},
```

#### addition.php

```
<div><?php echo get_the_title( (int) $_POST['post_id'] ); ?></div>
```

That will only work on posts/pages, of course. If you want the *site* title, that's a different function.

There may also be some errors that are causing the AJAX request to fail, so [make sure `WP_DEBUG` is enabled](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/wordpress/wp-config/#wp-debug), and check your PHP error log after a request.

You should also check your browser dev tools to see the raw HTTP response to the request, in case that includes any clues. Also `console.log( response )` instead of `response.responseJSON`, in case the JSON parsing is failing.

---

*P.S. There's [a Stack Exchange site specifically for WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), and you'll usually get better answers there.*